# Deducing a template function within a template function (using C++ concepts)

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

This code leads to an error, `error: no matching function to call to 'put'`.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>  // for is_invocable_r_v
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template <typename T, typename F>
    requires std::is_invocable_r_v<T, F, T, T>
void put(T& r, T a, T b, F f)
{
    r = f(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    put(x, 1, 2, add);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
}
```

This seems because concepts do not help deducing a template parameter, although they can constrain it.

I could define `put` using a function pointer instead of introducing the parameter `F`. But, it will exclude more general function objects such as (capturing) lambdas to be used for `f`.

```
template <typename T>
void put(T& r, T a, T b, T (f)(T, T))
{
    r = f(a, b);
}
```

Of course, I can be a little more specific, `put(x, 1, 2, add<int>)`, and it will work for this simple example. But, in a more generic situation like writing a library, I want the compiler to do it for me and determine the proper instance of `add` from the outer context.

Is it possible to let the compiler know `F` is a certain functional type and make it deduce as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with an extra overload you get the compiler to resolve `add` and you still support function objects.

```
template <typename T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template <typename T, typename F>
    requires std::is_invocable_r_v<T, F, T, T>
void put(T& r, T a, T b, F f)
{
    r = f(a, b);
}


template <typename T>
void put(T& r, T a, T b, T(f)(T,T))
{
    r = f(a, b);
}

auto template_lambda_add = []<class T>(T a, T b) -> T { return a + b; };

int main()
{
    int x;
    put(x, 1, 2, add);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    put(x, 1, 2, std::plus<void>{});
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    put(x, 1, 2, [](auto a, auto b){return a+b;});
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    put(x, 1, 2, template_lambda_add);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
}
```

edit:

template lambdas are also supported. ive added an example to demonstrate.

as an additional clarification, the syntax for a template lambda is as follows

```
auto lambda_add = []<class T>(T a, T b) -> T { return a + b; };
```

something like the following would be a templated variable declaration. i.e. a template for creating a lambda, rather than a tempalted lambda.

```
template <class T>
auto lambda_add = [](T a, T b) -> T { return a + b; };
```

edit2: some more stuff

> Can I also make a templated function object work?

yep. thats what [`std::plus<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) is basically.

you have to template the operator though and not the struct. for example

```
struct Add {
template <class T>
T operator()(T a, T b) { return a + b; } 
};
```

also as to why the overload `template <typename T> void put(T& r, T a, T b, T(f)(T,T)) { r = f(a, b); },` works

basically the compiler already knows what `T` is from the first 3 arguments, so it can use that to figure out how to instantiate `add`. to be more explicit about the fact that we want `T` to be deduced from the first 3 arguments and not the function ptr argument, we can use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) like so

```
template <typename T>
void put(T& r, T a, T b, std::type_identity_t<T(T,T)> f)
{
    r = f(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, I am afraid, I cannot use a template lambda like `template <typename T> auto lambda_add = [](T a, T b) -> T { return a + b; };`. Then, `put(x, 1, 2, lambda_add)` would lead to an error, `error: missing template arguments before ‘)’ token`.

Comment: I wonder how `[](auto a, auto b) { return a + b; }` works, which I think is the same as `template <typename T, typename U> [](T a, U b) { return a + b; }`. Isn't it?

Comment: @DongzinChoi i've updated my answer. let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know the new syntax for templated lamba. May I ask you just another question? Can I also make a templated function object work? E.g. With `template <typename T> struct Add { T operator()(T a, T b) { return a + b; } };` and `template <typename T> Add<T> function_object_add;`, how can I use `put(x, 1, 2, function_object_add)` without a compile error?

Comment: I think that current standard seems requiring a templated function should be resolved before being used in template parameter deduction. Right? But, as in the function pointer example, `template <typename T> void put(T& r, T a, T b, T(f)(T,T)) { r = f(a, b); }`, we can use a templated funtion in this case. I am confused.

Comment: @DongzinChoi no problem, I added some more to my answer. hope its helpful!